# How can I use Dispatch inside component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Actually, I am still confusing about Dispatch in nest component. I know that in redux, we can use dispatch in any level.

Firstly, I have reducer like below:

```
var defaultCommentState = {
    login_status: false,
    author_name: '',
    author_email: '',
    author_url: 'https://google.com',
    content: '',
    post:null,
    parent:0
}
const addComment = (state = defaultCommentState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_COMMENT':
            return {
                ...state, 
                login_status: action.login_status,
                author_name: action.author_name,
                author_email: action.author_email,
                content: action.content,
                postid: action.postid,
                parentid: action.parentid
            }
        default:
            return state; 
    }
}

export default addComment;
```

I have a component is `Comment List` where I can know the `postid` to add `Comment Form` corresponding to the post by postid.

```
class CommentList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    //In this component I can get postid like this.
    //I want to send this `postid` to store for using in another component.
    //How can I use Dispatch in this situation.

    var {postid} = this.props;


    this.state = {
      comments: [],
      page: 1,
      loadedDone: false,
      error: null,
    }
  }
   ....
   ....
}

   withRouter(CommentList)
```

How can I use Redux Dispatch in my component. 
I am sorry because I am new in Redux and I tried but no luck.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You should have this.props.dispatch, if not, you most likely forgot to wrap your app with Provider (from 'redux-form' package)

your component should look something like that:

to use the action you should import it

```
import myAction from './my-reducer';
```

then you should have function that call that action

```
invokeAction() {
  const { dispath } = this.props;
  dispatch(myAction());
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { myAction } from './my-action';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const { doSomething} = this.props;
    return <button onClick={ () => doSomething() } / >
  }
}

export default connect(
() => ({}), // Map state to props
dispatch => ({ doSomething: () => dispatch(myAction()) })
)(Test);
```

Comment: Hi. I use `var {dispatch} = this.props` but it return `dispatch is undefined`. I wrap with Provider and I am able to get state but unable to use `dispatch`

Comment: Can you add more detail to my component as well as how to connect for using `dispatch`. Thank you

Comment: I have three components in a file Detail.js. If I spitted into 3 three files with three components it can work well. If not it does not work